How to export Sectigo Code Signing Certificate to PFX for Electron Forge's Windows Code Signing?
I am building an Electron Forge app. I believe if I sign my app as my llc I will avoid the "Unknown Developer" popups users get when they run my exe. I'm doing this because the error is a scary UX.
I am trying to get a pfx file out of Sectigo usb to enable signing my app with a github action. I understand a usb wasn't always required.
Here are the steps I expect to follow based on Electron Forge's documentation:

Buy a Code Signing Certificate from Sectigo and go through their validation steps. I believe i bought the non-EV version.
Plug in the usb containing a signing certificate
Grab the password they sent in the email
Do something to get a pfx file
Update forge.config.js with:

{
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-squirrel',
      config: {
        certificateFile: './cert.pfx', <- I need this pfx file
        certificatePassword: process.env.CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD // <- This is the email password I asusme
      }
    }

What I tried to get a pfx file
Here are some of the ways I've tried to get the PFX. Sectigo's Knowledge Base is incredibly difficult to navigate and understand. I don't see one example of my pfx use case. Searching pfx only brings up an article that assumes you already have one.
Using SafeNet

Download and open SafeNet Authentication client, the app Sectigo suggests you use
Note the hierarchy Tokens -> My Company LLC -> User Certificates -> My Company LLC
Log into the outer My Company LLC token using the emailed password
Right click the inner My Company LLC token, export
Note that the only filetype option is .cer when a .pfx is what is needed

Using certmgr

Run certmgr.msc (note that searching cert manager with windows brings up the same app, but with different certs, I dont know why)
See My Company LLC in the list, issued by Sectigo Public Code Signing CA R36
Right click it, All Tasks, Export, Next
Note that the option Yes, export the private key is blurred out.
See Note: The associated private key is marked as not exportable. Only the certificate can be exported.

Signing it by hand

Run certmgr.msc
Double click My Company LLC, Details , scroll down through the fields
Copy the value of the Thumbprint field
Add signtool to path
Run make to get an electron forge exe
In an administrator bash, run

signtool sign /sha1 THUMBPRINT_OF_CERTIFICATE /tr http://timestamp.sectigo.com /td sha256 /fd sha256 /ksp "SafeNet Key Storage Provider" "path\to\program.exe"

This gives me
SignTool Error: Multiple certificates were found that meet all the given
        criteria. Use the /a option to allow SignTool to choose the best
        certificate automatically or use the /sha1 option with the hash of the
        desired certificate.
The following certificates meet all given criteria:
    Issued to: 12a07552-4d30-4fca-846c-a8be84912193
    Issued by: 12a07552-4d30-4fca-846c-a8be84912193
    Expires:   Sat Mar 29 01:32:52 2025
    SHA1 hash: HASH_ONE

    Issued to: 2f31b0a3-ea27-4cd2-9667-2b0d00c33f1d
    Issued by: 2f31b0a3-ea27-4cd2-9667-2b0d00c33f1d
    Expires:   Tue Mar 25 20:44:51 2025
    SHA1 hash: HASH_TWO

    Issued to: MY COMPANY LLC
    Issued by: Sectigo Public Code Signing CA R36
    Expires:   Thu May 22 18:59:59 2025
    SHA1 hash: MY_CERTIFICATE_THUMBPRINT

Despite running the signing command with /a and /sha1, this error is all i get.
Physical Device Requirement
I sort of understand that Microsoft now requires a physical device to sign apps. Does that mean that it will be impossible to sign my app with CI? Not having to build my apps by hand saves me thousands of human errors.
Some Links I found

Sectigo How Tos Youtube Playlist

Impenetrable Microsoft Explanation of Digital Signatures


What my key looks like



So you bought a signing certificate and what did you got? For building a pfx/p12 file we first need to know what you got from Sectigo, please update that in your question.

In the email the Product is listed as Code Signing Certificate. Issued Sectigo Public Code Signing CA R36, Produce Name: SafeNet e Token 5110+ CC (940B). Were any of these values what you were looking for? Im very new to this space so I dont know what is important to know, thanks for patience.

What files did you got from Sectigo (CA generated keys)? Or do you have to create a Certificate Signing Request (CSR)? Check the Sectigo documentation.

I added images regarding the nature of my certificates with blocked out sensitive info


I am trying to get a pfx file out of Sectigo usb to enable signing my app with a github action. I understand a usb wasn't always required.

This is not possible, you can't extract the private key from the USB token to a file based keystore. The new code signing keys delivered since June 1, 2023 must be stored on a hardware storage module.
Instead of creating a pfx file you have to set the signWithParams parameter in the squirrel configuration and specify the signtool parameters to use the USB token.
Something like this:
"makers": [
  {
    "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
    "config": {
      "signWithParams": " /a /tr http://rfc3161timestamp.globalsign.com/advanced /fd SHA256 /td SHA256 /sha1 [thumbprint]"
    }
  }
],


Thank you for this, this is hugely helpful. Still, this can only work on a machine where I am available to type in the password, and only on a computer with the physical token. So no continuous integration, right?

The password can be passed as a parameter, but you indeed need access to the token from the CI worker. Either through a proxy like https://github.com/iksaif/pkcs11-proxy or a service like SignServer. And the next time you renew your certificate you may want to use a cloud signing service like Azure Trusted Signing instead of a hardware token.

God I wish i knew that existed before going this far to use my token.

Thank You so much. This post is beneficial. The documentation for electron-forge and Sectigo is abysmal

This is perfectly working with squirrel but how to do with maker-wix as I want to create MSI file I tried same way but it is not working. Could you please help me @Emmanuel Bourg

to avoid inputting the password every time you can enable single logon, go to client settings then advanced and you will see the single logon button.

The question is about code-signing. If there is somewhere that it's useful to adjust login settings before attempting to sign, please edit the answer to clarify where these client settings are, and at what point in Olver's lengthy steps this should be done.

The initial answer, as Emmanuel Bourg said, is that you can't export pfx's using the new fangled physical tokens.
My larger solution was to sign OSX normally, and to send Windows files to an unsigned folder and sign them manually using a script.
Here's my CI process that I believe is as painless as possible for now:

Assuming you're publishing to s3, set the publisher-s3 to publish to an unsigned folder

        keyResolver: (fileName, platform, arch) => {
          return `${platform}/unsigned/${arch}/${fileName}`
        }


Set the updateElectronApp's updateSource and the
squirrel maker's remoteReleases to point an a /signed folder.

updateElectronApp({
      updateSource: {
        type: UpdateSourceType.StaticStorage,
        baseUrl: `https://BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/${process.platform}/${process.arch}`
      },
      updateInterval: '1 hour',
      logger: require('electron-log')
    })

{
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-squirrel',
      config: (arch) => ({
        ...
        remoteReleases: `https://BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/win32/${arch}`, 
      })
    }


Move the published OSX zip from the unsigned to signed s3 folder using the aws cli in the github action, as it signed remotely because Apple doesn't require physical tokens THANK GOD. Why send osx to an unsigned folder? Because specifying the os of the s3-publisher does nothing, so you have to make both go to the same bucket. Have two different publishers, one per os, creates duplicates.

However, for windows, we must look over each file in the unsigned folder, check if it has a signed version in the signed folder, and if it doesn't, download it, sign it, and upload it to the signed folder. A key thing to note is that the squirrel maker relies on the RELEASES file and the presence of nupkg files to create deltas, so be careful with deleting files that might be necessary later.

Make a bash script that you run every time you get a green build on github. If you are lazy and don't run it, then windows users just don't get new versions. I was afraid users would get new versions that weren't signed, but that is avoided.

...
sign_setup_exe() {
    local version=$1
    TIMESTAMP_SERVER="http://timestamp.sectigo.com"

    echo "Signing..."
    signtool sign -sha1 "$THUMBPRINT" -tr "$TIMESTAMP_SERVER" -td sha256 -fd sha256 "$LOCAL_DIR/APP-$version Setup.exe"
    signtool sign -sha1 "$THUMBPRINT" -tr "$TIMESTAMP_SERVER" -td sha256 -fd sha256 "$LOCAL_DIR/APP-win32-x64-$version/APP-$version Setup.exe"
}

process_setup_file() {
    local setup_file=$1
    local version

    version=$(echo "$setup_file" | grep -oP '(?<=APP-).*')

    echo "Considering $version..."
    if aws s3api head-object --bucket "BUCKET" --key "win32/x64/APP-win32-x64-$version.zip" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "BUCKET/win32/x64/APP-$version Setup.exe already exists so we are skipping."
        return 1
    fi

    download_files "$version"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Failed to download files for version $version."
        return 1
    fi
    unzip_file "$version"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Error Unzipping $version."
        return 1
    fi
    sign_setup_exe "$version"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Error signing $version."
        return 1
    fi
    rezip_directory "$version"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Error zipping directory signed files $version."
        return 1
    fi  
    upload_signed_files "$version"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Error uploading signed files $version."
        return 1
    fi    
    remove_local_files
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Error removing local files for $version."
        return 1
    fi
    return 0
}
# The releases file is used to manage versions, I think both post and getting versions relies on this.
copy_releases_file() {
    aws s3 cp s3://$TEMP_BUCKET/RELEASES s3://$FINAL_BUCKET/RELEASES
}
check_for_new_files() {
    echo "Checking for new setup.exe in $TEMP_BUCKET..."

    setup_files=$(aws s3 ls "s3://$TEMP_BUCKET/" | grep 'Setup.exe' | awk '{print $4}')

    for setup_file in $setup_files; do
        process_setup_file "$setup_file"
    done
    copy_releases_file
}
check_for_new_files

Is this sustainable for more than one person? No. Would getting a dedicated windows server for building your code solve this? No! Someone still has to walk up to the computer and give a password every time. I skimmed an article where a guy said he could give the password for the token once per session, but I dont know how they did it.

Did you try with Jsign (https://ebourg.github.io/jsign) instead of signtool? It's cross platform and you can pass the password on the command line: jsign --storetype ETOKEN --storepass 123456 setup.exe (disclaimer, I'm the author of this project).

im going to feel dumb, dont you use different certificates for osx and micosoft?

That's correct. But you can sign the Windows binaries on macOS, no need to have a Windows server for that.
